# N balls and M boxes question

Tags: probability

We were asked this question in class and asked to try to solve it on our own, but we can't get it.

$N$ balls are thrown uniformly randomly into M boxes, with multiple occupancy permitted.  Prove that the expected number of empty boxes is $\frac{(M-1)^N}{M^{N-1}}$

Answer (score 4):

For $i=1,2,\dots, M$, define  random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th box is empty, and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $Y$ of empty boxes is given by  $$Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_M.$$

By the linearity of expectation, the expected number $E(Y)$ of empty boxes is given by
$$E(Y)=E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_M)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)\cdots +E(X_M).$$

A ball misses Box $i$ with probability $\frac{M-1}{m}$. So **all** the balls miss Box $i$ with probability $\Pr(X_i=1)=\left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^N$.

Add up over all the $i$, or eqivalently multiply  by $M$ to find $E(Y)$.

Comment: Where does the M-1/M come from?  We weren't able to figure that part out.  We knew to use the linearity to break it up like that, but didnt get the next step

Comment: Imagine throwing the first ball. It hits Box $i$ with probability $\frac{1}{M}$, so misses with probability $\frac{M-1}{M}$. For the probability they **all** miss Box $i$, raise to the $N$-th power.